# how to migrate database from mysql to mssql?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, database, database-migration

I have a web server in `php` and `my sql` .Now I have to upgrade the same server from my `php` to `asp` and `my sql` to `mssql`.
I have to write the whole `php` code in `asp` but I think I can direct migrate the database from `my sql` to `mssql` to save much more time. in the `my sql` database there is no user input data as it the new totaly server.
Just I want to take whole structure of the database to the `mssql`.
After google some time there is a tool from microsoft called(**Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL**) when I try to migrate the database I got an error that the destination table doesnot exit .
can some body help me to **migrate the database including keys** from `mysql` to `mssql`

Comment: You migrate databases one table at a time, then one stored procedure at a time, one function at a time, and so on.  If you are looking for a tool recommendation, then Stack Overflow is the wrong forum.  If you have a specific question, include sample code from both databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thnx for relpy.if i go through this I cannot maintain my keys(foreign keys)

Comment: Both databases support foreign keys and both do so with very similar syntax.  There shouldn't be a problem moving foreign key references from one database to another.  You will probably need manual intervention to get it right.